# How get self value from row to use in another select query in the self eloquent model?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm new at the laravel, Just started at few days ago and I already searched about this but nothing found about my question.
For example... I have the **offers** and **offers_prices** table.

*offers:*

```
+----+-----------+
| id |   name    |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Product 1 |
|  2 | Product 2 |
|  3 | Product 3 |
|  4 | Product 4 |
+----+-----------+
```

*offers_prices:*

```
+----+------------+-------+---------------------+
| id |  offer_id  | price |     created_at      |
+----+------------+-------+---------------------+
|  1 |          1 | 65.90 | 2020-12-17 16:00:00 |
|  2 |          1 | 64.99 | 2020-12-17 17:00:00 |
|  3 |          1 | 58.90 | 2020-12-17 18:00:00 |
|  4 |          1 | 60.99 | 2020-12-17 19:00:00 |
+----+------------+-------+---------------------+
```

To get the current offer price (**60.99**) I have created the function below to get it from a relationship eloquent model:

*Models/Offer.php*

```
public function price() {
    return parent::hasOne(OfferPrices::class)
        ->where("date", "<=", \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
        ->orderBy("date", "DESC")
        ->limit(1);
}
```

And now I want to get the most recent previous price but higher than current price like in the query below:

```
SELECT *
FROM offers_prices
WHERE offers_prices.offer_id = 1
AND
offers_prices.price > (
    SELECT offers_prices.price
    FROM offers_prices
    WHERE offers_prices.offer_id = 1
    AND offers_prices.date <= NOW()
    ORDER BY offers_prices.date DESC
    LIMIT 1
)
AND offers_prices.date <= NOW()
ORDER BY offers_prices.date DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

It means that the recent previous and higher than current price **can't be** **58.90** because it's lower than current *(60.99)*. **Must be 64.99**.
How can I do it? I have tried creating another function in the self eloquent model:

*Models/Offer.php*

```
public function prev_high_price() {
    return parent::hasOne(OfferPrices::class)
        ->where("date", "<=", \Carbon\Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
        ->where("price", ">", $this->price()->price)
        ->orderBy("date", "DESC")
        ->limit(1);
}
```

But it doesn't work..

Answer (score 1):

You're using the `hasOne` relationship for a database relationship that looks more like a `hasMany`. Your `Offers` can have many `Prices`. Your table naming is outwith convention too as you're not using a pivot table but have named your `offers_prices` table as if it was.

***Off topic to the question but relevant to your situation, it's advisable to not store currency values as floats or doubles. Store them as integers in the lowest denominator.***

To answer your question, given the following two migrations:

**Offers table migration**

```
class CreateOffersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('offers', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->string('name');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('offers');
    }
}
```

**Prices table migration**

```
class CreatePricesTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('prices', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->foreignId('offer_id');
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->foreign('offer_id')->references('id')->on('offers');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('prices');
    }
}
```

Define the following in your `Offer` model:

```
class Offer extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function prices()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Price::class);
    }

    public function lastPrice()
    {
        return $this->prices()->orderBy('id', 'desc')->limit(1);
    }

    public function lastHighPrice()
    {
        return $this->prices()
            ->where('id', '<', $this->lastPrice()->first()->id)
            ->orderBy('price', 'desc')
            ->limit(1);
    }
}
```

Run your migration and database seeders (if you have any, otherwise just add data manually). In your terminal and whilst you're current working directory is your Laravel project, fire up `tinker`:

```
php artisan tinker
```

From inside tinker, you can now play around with your data and models.

```
// get a collection of all prices for the Offer with id 1
Offer::find(1)->prices

// get a collection with the last price for the offer with id 1
Offer::find(1)->lastPrice

// get a collection with the previous highest price for the offer with id 1
Offer::find(1)->lastHighPrice
```

Comment: It works when "find(id)" but not worked when I try to get it from UserOffersFavorited in User Model: 

See https://prnt.sc/w53ben

But When it run the `$this->price()->first()->price` it doesn't get the price from the foreign offer id. When I trace the variable above it just return the first price from all the table indepedent of the offer_id (what should not happen)

Comment: @CarlosLoureiro Well yeah, nowhere in your original question did you make reference to a `User` or `UserOffersFavorited` model or database table and neither of the table examples contain a reference to a `User`. That sounds like an entirely different question.

Comment: Yeah. But you know how can I make it work in the way that I need?

Comment: @CarlosLoureiro Not without knowing more about your use case such as how  you are defining UserOffersFavorited. That is a different question to the one you asked however and so should be a new thread. The question you asked has been answered.